# How to get the all names (not values) in office.js?

Tags: javascript, office-js, scriptlab

I have several "named" ranges. I am trying to get the **name** of the ranges, not the values.

I have tried the following :

```
$("#get-values").click(getValues);

async function getValues() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("FormName");
            const valm = sheet.names;
            valm.load("names");
            await context.sync();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(valm.names));
        });
    } catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get the names from the above script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `names` collection is accessible at the Workbook level:

```
async function run() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        var names = context.workbook.names;
        names.load();
        await context.sync();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(names));
    });
}
```

This is will result in a `NamedItemCollection` containing `NotedItems` similar to this:

```
{
    "comment": "",
    "name": "Range Name",
    "scope": "Workbook",
    "type": "Range",
    "value": "Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1",
    "visible": true
}
```

The address for the range is held in the `value` property. You can use this to determine which sheet a given range is found.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel the named ranges are parts of a collection `.Names`. Find a way to refer this collection and loop it. In VBA it is like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim name As name
    For Each name In ThisWorkbook.names
        Debug.Print name
        Debug.Print name.NameLocal
    Next name

End Sub
```

Comment: I know some people won't, but I quite like to see `name` used as the variable name here. That's exactly what it is, after all... +1

Comment: @CallumDA - which is a bit strange, because I have no problems with `name` as a variable, but I really get a strange feeling when I see `dim cell`. :)

Comment: @Vityata I am not going with VB I'm trying to do with Office.js. I have tried  something like `sheet.names` but it is giving the null values. Can you help me out using the office.js

Comment: @mkHun - try to find a way to refer to the workbook object in `js`. Once you refer to it, refer to the `.Names` collection and loop it. The idea of the VBA code was to show you what to do.